# What does char *derp[20] mean?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Also: 
Does this code make sense? (I'm new to C, so not sure)

```
char*s1 = derp[0]; 
char*s2 = derp[1];
```

I feel that derp is an array of pointers to chars (i.e. an array of strings), and I'm trying to get out two strings out of the array. However, when I try to pass these two char*'s into a function (whose prototype is FindMaxOverlap(char*long, char*short), the compiler throws me an error saying that there is an implicit definition of the FindMaxOverlap function).

Comment: Yes, this is an array of `char *`, but the compiler error is unrelated (that's probably related to a missing header file).

Comment: Note that `long` and `short` are reserved keywords.

Comment: "Implicit definition..." means that the compiler hasn't seen a prototype for the function you're calling, so is guessing at what it takes and returns.  It's almost always wrong, though.  :P  Check whether you're including the header that declares that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 char *derp[20]:
```

declares `derp` as an array `20` of pointer to `char`.

```
char*s1 = derp[0];
```

declares `s1` a pointer to `char` initialized with the first pointer to `char` element of `derp`. It makes sense as long as the first element of `derp` has been correctly allocated, for example using `malloc`.

You can pass `s1` and `s2` to your `FindMaxOverlap` function, but `derp[0]` and `derp[1]` have to point to valid objects.

When you call `FindMaxOverlap` function, the `FindMaxOverlap` has to be declared in your source file, for example using an include file or by declaring a prototype at file scope.

Also note that `long` and `short` are keywords in C and you cannot use them as identifiers for function parameters.

Comment: See cHao's comment, the issue here has nothing to do with `char` or allocation, it's just about library includes.

Comment: Thanks! It was being caused by me using the short and long keywords which were reserved :P